# DropDownList Formatting?

Tags: jquery, css, html, html-datalist

Is there a way to format the dropdownlist like the picture, where I am showing two field columns, when I click the dropdown?  If so, can this be done with HTML5 datalist or jquery?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the IgniteUI library to control the style of the Combobox. I created a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/u5cdLvo5/)

HTML

```
<div id="combo"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {

    var data = [{
        "ID": 1,
            "Name": "John Smith",
            "Age": 45
    }, {
        "ID": 2,
            "Name": "Mary Johnson",
            "Age": 32
    }, {
        "ID": 3,
            "Name": "Bob Ferguson",
            "Age": 27
    }];

    $("#combo").igCombo({
        dataSource: data, //JSON Array defined above         
        valueKey: "ID",
        textKey: "Name",
        width: "360px",
        itemTemplate: "<div class='comboItemContainer'><div class='colOne'>${Name}</div><div class='colTwo'>${Age}</div></div>"
    });

});
```

CSS

```
.comboItemContainer {
    width: auto;
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
.colOne {
    border-right: 1px dashed gray;
    float: left;
    width: 300px
}
.colTwo {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```